# How to express that you got fever

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

How to express that you caught fever -

1. I have got fever so we won't meet today
2. I caught fever
3. I am having fever
4. I am suffering from fever
5. I am feverish

Comment: You could just say 'I have a fever'.

Comment: Generally speaking, a "fever" is a ***symptom*** of some disease that you might "catch" (if you caught Covid, for example, you might be ***suffering*** from a fever). In your context, assuming you don't want to go into details about the specific disease that's making you feel bad, the most common way of phrasing it would probably be *I'm **feeling feverish**, so we won't meet today*. Or perhaps *I have **a touch of fever**...*

Comment: Personally though, I'm not sure many people would want to go into detail about the exact nature of their "indisposition" when excusing themselves from going to work or a business meeting, as seems to be the context here. I'd probably just say *I'm feeling a bit under the weather, so I won't be coming in to work today*. And I'd resent the boss asking me to give further details as to exactly what my symptoms were (it's none of his business if I've got a bad case of "the runs" from last night's curry! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I was working, if you 'phoned in sick' you were required to state the nature of the indisposition!

Comment: @KateBunting: Even if it was a bad case of pmt?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Personnel/HR required some kind of statement of the reason for absence - I suppose it could be tactfully worded if required.

Comment: @KateBunting: My first "proper" job was working for the British Civil Service, where everyone was entitled to "self-certificate" themselves off sick for up to 14 days a year - usually, *with no questions asked*. I soon discovered that some people would happily sign themselves off for a fortnight just to go away on a second summer holiday. Anyway, after working there a few months I was called in to see the boss and hauled over the coals because I'd been taking almost every Tuesday morning off sick. Because I was spending every Monday night drunk as a skunk in our local jazz club!

Answer (score 1):

Here the most simple is best:

> I have a fever.

You could have "have got" or "suffering from".  These are correct, but in this case simple is the best way.  In the context you give, details are not really needed.  Moreover "have" is normally preferred to "have got", "be having" is often a mistake, except in idioms, and "suffering from" is implied (nobody enjoys a fever!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just feverish: **I have (got/caught) a fever.**
If you know what fever you have got/caught, e.g.: **I have caught Rheumatic fever.**
or, if others are already suffering from it: **I have got/caught the fever.**
Alternatively, **I am suffering from a/the fever.**
If you just have a high temperature: **I am feverish.**